# Problem with Firebase API Restriction settings

Tags: reactjs, firebase, github-pages

I have a problem with the Firebase API Restriction settings.
I want to add HTTP restrictions to secure the data but when I add restrictions, it is not working. What am I doing wrong here?

- Website deployed with Github Pages (ex.https://username.github.io/project-name/) It is a React app deployed following this description: https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages
- I am using Firebase Authentication. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-create-email-password
- To secure the API key(although I know Firebase API is no problem, just in case), I wanted to set like below in Google Cloud⇒API & Services⇒Credentials

  1. application restrictions: HTTP referrers
  2. web site restrictions: https://username.github.io/project-name/* (used
     /* since there are many paths in the website)
     (When I leave no.2 empty and accept all web sites, it works so probably this setting is wrong...)

Comment: When you add restrictions, its expected not to work, right? Or am I missing something here.

Comment: On the Google Cloud website, it says "Restrict key usage requests to the specified websites". So I thought it restricts access only to the entered website (I want to accept access only from the GitHub Page).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to restrict different paths with `*` with a previous defined path. What I mean is that you can use `*` to specify any path to a specific domain `https://username.github.io/*` (CORRECT), but not to a path `https://username.github.io/project-name/*` (INCORRECT).

You can take a look to this official [website](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys?hl=es_419&_ga=2.184621356.-467516901.1692777363#adding_http_restrictions). It looks like the only option to restrict access in your case, is to add all the exact paths (`https://username.github.io/project-name/home`, `https://username.github.io/project-name/about`, `https://username.github.io/project-name/contact`...)